# Sending flow to switch's default case

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, switch-statement

Hi all,

I have in my js file:

```
function sendDataToPhp()
{
  theUrl = 'myfile.php';
    params = '';
    params += 'function=sendData';

    params += '&myfield='+someVariableForMyField;
    $.ajax ({
        url: theUrl,
        data: params,
        type: "POST",
        async:false,
        success: function (data, textStatus)
        {    
        }
    }); 

}
```

Then in myfile.php

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['function']))
    {
        $function = $_REQUEST['function'];

    }  


    switch ($function) {
        case 'sendData':
        //code
        break;
        default:
       //code
}
```

With this I'm sending the code flow to the sendData case of the switch.

Now Inside the success, in the ajax() I need to send the code flow to the default case of the switch. How can I do that?

Thanks a million!

Comment: just don't send `function=sendData` in the params it will go to the `default`, much better if you can make that as an argument in the `sendDataToPhp(function_name)` so you can re-use it with or without it

Comment: Is there any way to do what I'm asking (inside the success, in ajax()  the flow to go to the default case)? Otherwise I will have to change a lot of code

Comment: if you make it a parameter to `sendDataToPhp('function=sendData')` or `sendDataToPhp('function=dontexist')` <-- call this again inside of success, make the function re-usable or something, might not be a good practice IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way Switch works is if there isn't a matching CASE then it goes to DEFAULT case ... so perhaps you can provide `function=IdontExistFunction` in your ajax call ... OR if there is piece of code in DEFAULT you want to run then best to separate it and make it a function so that you can call from anywhere as required.

BTW - There is GOTO statement available too - not sure if you can make use of it in your case http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php ?

Comment: It is a good idea the one about IdontExistFunction  but I guess there's no way to send  params += 'function=IdontExistFunction'; inside the success in ajax(). Am I right?

Comment: goto should be a jquery statement, I'm controlling the flow via the js file

Comment: I have never tried to make another ajax call inside an ajax succes function - maybe you can try calling your JS function to make another ajax call with IDontExist param - but I think your approach/logic of whatever you are trying to achieve is wrong somewhere

Comment: the IdontExistFunction approach worked outside the success ajax(). Thanks a million for the clue!!